# how to hide required pop-up of input in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hide pop-up of `required` of input using `javascript` [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rz6np/)

try to submit with empty input and see the pop-up, so i don't need to display           that pop-up and i want the required to validate.

any help i don't need to display any warning.

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" required="required" value="" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: So to understand this correctly, you want to validate the form, but don't want the notification?

Comment: yes i need the validation but not display notification.

Comment: See my comment on Rafa's answer.

Comment: yes @Johan i need validation to work but not displaying notification.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since this is a HTML5 Event you can prevent the event from triggering the popup **and** still provide validation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/invalid). A simple event listener will do the job.

To handle focus include an id to that field like so ...

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required="required" value="" />
```

And handle that focus within the return function ...

JS

```
document.addEventListener('invalid', (function () {
  return function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("name").focus();
  };
})(), true);
```

**EDIT**
Check it out
http://jsfiddle.net/rz6np/9/

Comment: I need just the placeholder cursor to keep blinking with no pop up in the input area however this remove pop up only.

Comment: @kadibra just add logic after the `e.preventDefault();`  something like         `document.getElementById("focusMe").focus();`  where `focusMe` is the id of the element you want focused (in your case the input text)

Comment: @kadibra Just like Johan said just focus onto that element. Check out the edit I made.

Comment: Just note that the invalid event gets called for every input that needs validation.

Answer (score 3):

```
autocomplete="off"
```

or

```
autocomplete="nope"
```

If autocomplete still works on an `<input>` despite having autocomplete="off", but you can change `off` to a random string, like *nope*.

It appears that Chrome now ignores `autocomplete="off"` unless it is on the `<form>`-tag.