# How to remove validation-bubble-message in form validation

Tags: html, css, forms, validation

```css
::-webkit-validation-bubble-message {
 display: none;
}
'
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" name="" required="">
<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How to remove validation-bubble-message in form validation, I have used

```
::-webkit-validation-bubble-message {
    display: none;
}
```

But it is not working. And request to without using novalidate attribute.

```
form novalidate="novalidate">
...
form>
```

and need to used

```
input  required="required"
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with Javascript like so

Reference: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401437/how-to-hide-required-pop-up-of-input-in-html)

```js
document.addEventListener('invalid', (function () {
  return function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("fname").focus();
  };
})(), true);
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```