# setCustomValidity position changes when input width increase

Tags: html, css

I've got two inputs with setCustomValidity.

In the first input setCustomValidity position is in left position, in other words, is in correct position, like in the below image:

[image]

but in the another one the property setCustomValidity tooltip appears in the middle, like in the below image:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <label>Code:</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="3" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(); "/>

        <label>Description:</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="3" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity();" style="width: 500px;"/>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I put tooltip on the left position, Like in the first image?

Comment: You'll need to add some code so we can see what the issue is. From the picture, a guess would be .myform label  { text-align: left; }

Comment: @InvariantChange I'm so sorry, for forget the code, i'll tried your solution, but not works.

Comment: Do you have the CSS too?

Comment: @InvariantChange sorry again.

Comment: Still missing most of the CSS :p

Comment: @InvariantChange Now I simplify the question :P

Comment: Without enough code, it can't be answered.

Comment: @InvariantChange There is all code, I'm not using external css. Only HTML

Comment: Oh, my bad. just looking into it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You Can't Change it

> For whatever reason, we developers (or more likely our designer
>   colleagues) have a deep-seated desire to style these things. But
>   unfortunately we can’t, as zero browsers provide styling hooks that
>   target these bubbles. Chrome used to provide a series of vendor
>   prefixed pseudo-elements (::-webkit-validation-bubble-*), but they
>   were removed in Chrome 28.
>
> So what’s a developer to do? Well, although browsers don’t allow you
>   to customize their bubbles, the constraint validation spec does allow
>   you to suppress the browser’s bubble UI and build your own. The rest
>   of the article shows you how to do just that.
>
> [Source](https://developer.telerik.com/featured/building-html5-form-validation-bubble-replacements/)

---

### Remove & Replace

However, You can remove it and use something else instead.

See: [How to remove validation-bubble-message in form validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47843199/how-to-remove-validation-bubble-message-in-form-validation)

An alternative solution, use an `alert`

See: [Invalid Alert](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_oninvalid)

Comment: Perfect, using "alert" make the solution easy to build my own tooltip.