# .NET MVC disable native validation message on time input

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an input field of type `time` as following

```html
<input type="time" name="visible-start-time" id="visible-start-time" class="form-control half-input" value="@(Model==null?"":Model.StartTime.TimeOfDay.ToString())"/>
```

[image]

I do not want the native `html` validation message to be shown.

Comment: As far as I know is that not possible

Comment: Maybe this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401437/how-to-hide-required-pop-up-of-input-in-html) will help you further

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `novalidate` attribute to your `<form>` tag to disable the browsers native validation (For all controls).

It's explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-novalidate)